# Parameter k in cmd/ps

Tags: apache, command-line, parameters

"C:\Server\bin\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe -k install"(launched by admin) - installing apache service

What does -k parameter mean, what values can it have and what other parameters can i specify(i know one more - -n(smth like setting a name))?

Comment: Why is the powershell tag being used in the question? I don't see PS related code. You'll probably find your answer in the official Apache documentation.

Comment: [RTM](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/httpd.html).

Answer (score 0):

Apache docs(forgot about commands of other utilities) - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/httpd.html